# running a web application from unitests with selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, iis

Im using selenium to test baselines of screen shots of my product 
and trying to run an automated tests within tfs 2013 build which i got installed on another machine but for me to run the tests first i need to run the website from VS so the iis will host it and than the tests will run correctly

im searching for a C# code for running the web app[which is a child of default Web site ] anyone got any idea?

Comment: I would separate these responsibilities. Have Jenkins or teamcity or whatever tools you use to build and deploy stuff start up the webapp somewhere, and then trigger your tests to run after the deploy is complete. If you're running these locally, you can create a simple script(not in your c# test code) to deploy the webapp to localhost and run your tests against that.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer myself 
used this code to get from registry the IIS path and then ran the site application with the IIS

```
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\IISExpress\\10.0");
        Object o = null;
        if (key != null)
        {
             o = key.GetValue("InstallPath");
        }
        Process cmd = new Process();

        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        cmd.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = cmd.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite && o != null)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(@"cd {0}", o);
                sw.WriteLine(@"iisexpress /path:{0}\mysit /port:whateverport", GetRootDirectory(context));

            }
        }
```